# How to share data between controllers in angular app in the right way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well, seems that this is not the first question about this subject, but...

I know that we can use service or events for this, but there are many posts on the internet which says that we should not use events a lot.

I also know that we can create separate service for this purpose, but in my opinion, its also not so good. How to "watch" for data changes? How to notify that smth has been changed? Events? Again?...

And also what about performance of each of these variants?

So, actually what is the real good and probably, the best way to share data between controllers in angular application? Moreover, is it a good idea to do this thing? Does it mean that we have something wrong in our application, some architectural or conceptual problems? Maybe this smells of smth?

Please point me and give a good advise

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

This is mostly common question, because sometimes I have to do this. And I want to know is it a good, is it correct with angular principals?

Comment: Do you have a specific case? different cases have different answers to this question. there is also scope inheritance which could be a way to do this.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use services to store/cache/call api to get/store data.  As far as tracking data change in different controllers and directives, you can use watch or events.  I personally hate watch, but do have to use at time.  I like to user events to track for user interactions and push the data change by calling functions in other controllers and directives.  Emit to me is the same as watch.

Comment: Services are great for sharing data between controllers, since they can be injected as and when required plus they are easy to write unit tests for since they can be tested in isolation

Comment: It depends a lot on the relation and the responsibilities & concerns between the controllers

Comment: @mindparse, yes, I also think about this. but you can notify other controller that smth has been change in this case? shall we use pub/sub or smth similar?

Comment: can you give an example of one controller which needs to notify another one?

Comment: @MoLow, I tried to create controllers with single responsibilities. If this is controllers of this view - its only for this view. but if this is a controller of navigation, for example?

Comment: @MoLow, ok. I have app where I have separate controllers for each view. also I have to control user navigation in navbar and sidebar. if you retrieve data for one view with controller of this view, but user types smth in navbar search, how to send this to that controller for loading appropriate data?

Comment: good exapmle.. I would use an object in the rootScope which will then be shared between all scopes. remember you should use an object and not a premitives for that

Comment: @MoLow, ok. and and what about notification? how actual controller will know that he must read that object and do smth?

Comment: I am writing an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is using scope inheritance:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.sharedObj = {search:''};
}])
.controller('navCtr',['$scope',function($scope){
}])
.controller('routeCtr',['$scope',function($scope){
  $scope.$watch("sharedObj.search",function(d){
    $scope.data = d ? 'Searched data is ' + d : '';
  });
}]);
```

```css
.main div{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation{
  width: 20%
}
.navigation input{
  max-width: 70%;
}

.page {
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" class="main">
  <div ng-controller="navCtr" class="navigation">
    search: <br/>
    <input ng-model="sharedObj.search"/>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="routeCtr" class="page">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</div>
```

the second way would be a shared service:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.factory('srcObject',[function(){
  return {
    value: ''
  }
}])
.controller('navCtr',['$scope', 'srcObject', function($scope, srcObject){
  $scope.search = srcObject;
}])
.controller('routeCtr',['$scope', 'srcObject', function($scope, srcObject){
  $scope.$watch(function(){return srcObject.value},function(d){
    $scope.data = d ? 'Searched data is ' + d : '';
  });
}]);
```

```css
.main div{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.navigation{
  width: 20%
}
.navigation input{
  max-width: 70%;
}

.page {
  width: 75%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" class="main">
  <div ng-controller="navCtr" class="navigation">
    search: <br/>
    <input ng-model="search.value"/>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="routeCtr" class="page">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the context of the controller directly to the service. This gives you several benefits: (1) you don't have to use `$scope` a lot; (2) you don't have to define properties in your directive's isolate scopes; (3) you don't have to touch `$rootScope`; (4) you don't have to use `$watch` or `$observe`, since *everything* that needs to be bound to something will be bound to the internal API of your global service.

This pattern is useful for applications that need to share *and be aware of* lots of data between a large number of components. I used this pattern in a video player where many distantly-related parts of the application had to share information and have access to each other's state: for instance, how many video players were in the view, the current time, duration and source of each player, etc.

This pattern isn't particularly suited for building truly reusable components. If you choose to use a service like this, the directive is hardcoded to rely on a certain service. However, you can define all the properties your application's components need in a single `value` component which is handy for defining your internal API.

With dirty checking, I'm not sure if sharing a potentially large object is a performance burden.

**directive**

```
function() {
    return {
        //if you want the service to hold all the data the directive needs
        //you don't need to define any properties here
        scope: {},
        controller: "SomeCtrl"
    };
}
```

**directive's controller**

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .controller("SomeCtrl", ["globalService", function(globalService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.globalService = globalService;
    }]);
```

**html**

```
<div>{{vm.globalService.someProperty}}</div>
```

**in some deeply nested template url**

```
<!-- another tradeoff is the long naming that can result -->

<div 
    ng-click="panel.state = !panel.state;"
    ng-repeat="panel in vm.globalService.dashboard.sidebar.panelConfig">{{panel.display}}</div>
```

**constants**

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .value("internalAPI", {
        someInitializedThing: true,
        someConfig: [
            { state: true, display: "foobar" },
            { state: false, display: "starts off false" }
        ],
        dashboard: {
            sidebar: {
                panelConfig: [
                    { display: "one panel", state: true },
                    { display: "special panel", state: false }
                ]
            }
        }  
    });
```

**let your service register the API you've defined**

```
angular
    .module("app")
    .service("globalService", ["internalAPI", function(API) {
        var tmp = {};
        for (var p in API)
            tmp[p] = API[p];
        return tmp;
    }])

    //now someplace else, globalService.someNavBar = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my post here about using services to share data between controllers: http://erikaugust.com/thoughts/angularjs-use-the-service-not-the-controller/?ws=so

There's a link to a JSFiddle example at the bottom of the blog post that will help.