# Accessing one controller data from another

Tags: angularjs

I want to use data from one controller to another , can any one please help me. For example :

```
  .controller('firstCtrl',function($scope){
   $scope.item = [{id:1, name:'John'},{id:2, name:'carter'},{id:3, name:'barsoom'},..]
   })
   .controller('secondCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.jsondata = item;
    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.jsondata));
   })
```

Is it possible. can any one please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to share data between controllers in angular app in the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442752/how-to-share-data-between-controllers-in-angular-app-in-the-right-way)

Comment: Hi.. Thank for reply. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257798/accessing-data-from-one-controller-to-another) , bit explained in detail

Comment: please help me to get through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{name}}

    </div>

    <div ng-controller="c">
        {{name}}

    </div>


</body>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

    $rootScope.name = "vipin";

}]).controller('c', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope) {


}])
```

Run this code you can get $rootScope.name value in both controller

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {

        $rootScope.name = "vipin";
    }]).controller('c', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope) {


    }])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">    
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
        {{name}}
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="c">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank you for reply. I tried, it is not working.

Comment: Hi.. Thank for reply. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257798/accessing-data-from-one-controller-to-another) , bit explained in detail

Comment: Thank you very much.. your code helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure. happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share data between controllers, you should use Angular Services. They are singleton that are intended to be used to share common code in your application. So, it is a good practice to put, for example, your $http request, or some data that is used in many places.

Some example would be:

https://jsfiddle.net/relferreira/2b5amcya/

JS:

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', mainController);

mainController.$inject = ['UserService'];

function mainController(UserService){

    var vm = this;
  vm.name = UserService.getName();

}

angular.module('app')
    .controller('DetailController', detailController);

detailController.$inject = ['UserService'];

function detailController(UserService){

    var vm = this;
  vm.name = UserService.getName();
  vm.other = 'test';

}

angular.module('app')
    .factory('UserService', userService);

function userService(){
    var name = 'Renan'; 
  return{
    getName: getName
  }

  function getName(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-ng-app="app">

  <div data-ng-controller="MainController as mainVm">
    {{mainVm.name}}
  </div>

  <div data-ng-controller="DetailController as detailVm">
    {{detailVm.name}}
    {{detailVm.other}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi.. Thank for reply. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257798/accessing-data-from-one-controller-to-another) , bit explained in detail

Answer (score 0):

You can use **event broadcast** or  **Service** to inject in controller.

Method 1:

```
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$broadcast('Test_Data',{ data: {} });
  })
myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('Test_Data', function(event, args) {
        var data= args.data
      // do something useful here;
    });
  });
```

Method 2 :

```
     myApp.factory('TestData', function () {
        var data = {};
            var setData=function(){...}
        return data;
      });
    myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, TestData) {
        $scope.data = TestData;
      })
```

Comment: Hi .. Thank you for reply. I was trying first method , **$scope.$broadcast('Test_Data',{ data: {} });** In this line can you please explain "{ data;{} }". How can I use in my code.

Comment: I tried with it : **$scope.$broadcast('Test_Data', $scope.item);** is it correct..??

Comment: Hi.. Thank for reply. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257798/accessing-data-from-one-controller-to-another) , bit explained in detail